# Log4j 2 JSON pattern layout + Logging JSON payload

Tags: java, json, logging, log4j2, elastic-stack

I am using ELK stack along with **log4j 2 via sl4j with `json` pattern layout** to log messages. All my logs are logged as `json` messages.Also in one of my logs I am trying to log the `json` response received from the third party service. But this response `json` body is not appended to the `json` structure. But it rather appended as a string including the escape characters.

**how the ultimate logs being logged out.**

```
 {
    "timeMillis": 1471862316416,
    "thread": "FioranoMQ Pubsub Session Thread",
    "level": "INFO",
    "loggerName": "com.mlp.eventing.bridge.fiorano.TopicMessageListener",
    "message": "{\"Msgtype\":\"SentToRabbitMqTest\",\"MessageData\":\"10\",\"opration\":\"devide\"}",
    "endOfBatch": false,
    "loggerFqcn": "org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLogger",
    "threadId": 28,
    "threadPriority": 5
}
```

In above message segment is appended as escaped strings rather than the entire `json` structure. My expected out put should be

```
{
    "timeMillis": 1471862316416,
    "thread": "FioranoMQ Pubsub Session Thread",
    "level": "INFO",
    "loggerName": "com.mlp.eventing.bridge.fiorano.TopicMessageListener",
    "message": {
        "Msgtype": "SentToRabbitMqTest",
        "MessageData": "10",
        "opration": "devide"
    },
    "endOfBatch": false,
    "loggerFqcn": "org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLogger",
    "threadId": 28,
    "threadPriority": 5
}
```

I am expecting to extract the fields in the  message segment using the grok filters for `json` in `shipper.conf`

Below are my configurations :-
log4j2.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="info"> <!-- log4j internals tracing -->
    <properties>
        <property name="pattern">%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} | %-5.5p | %-20.20C:%-5.5L | %msg%n</property>
        <property name="filePath">/opt/mlp/logs</property> 
        <property name="fileName">logs</property>
    </properties>
    <Appenders>
        <RollingFile name="RollingFile" fileName="${filePath}/${fileName}.log"
                     filePattern="${filePath}/${fileName}-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}-%i.log" append="true">
            <JSONLayout complete="false" compact="true" eventEol="true" />  
            <PatternLayout>
                <pattern>${pattern}</pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
            <Policies>
                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="1000 KB"/> 
            </Policies>l
        </RollingFile>
        <Console name="STDOUT" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout>
                <pattern>${pattern}</pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
        </Console>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Root level="debug">
            <AppenderRef ref="RollingFile"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="STDOUT"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

sample code snippet

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

class A {
private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Main.class);

public void testMethod()  {

JSONObject responseJson = callService();// json simple object
LOG.info(responseJson);

}

}
```

maven dependencies

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.21</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- end adding sl4j 2 for the message bridge -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--
        to enable json support for log4j enable following libraries
        -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.5</version>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: Did you end up solving your issue?

Comment: This might seem like a dumb question, but isn't the third party response a string and not an Object? Because if so, then everything was perfect with the logging and you just needed to parse the response.

Comment: I have a similar issue. The Log4J Json Layout escapes the string so the output printed to file is not a valid json. The pattern layout prints without escaping.

Answer (score 17):

To be able to log JSON unescaped, you should use Log4j2 logger instead of Slf4j. This feature is available starting from Log4j 2.11.

Log4j logger is able to log `ObjectMessage`, which will be converted to a nested JSON.
`ObjectMessage` constructor accepts Map, so JSONObject have to be converted to map (e.g. with help of Jackson `ObjectMapper`).

In the layout configuration add `objectMessageAsJsonObject="true"`:

```
<JSONLayout complete="false" compact="true" eventEol="true" objectMessageAsJsonObject="true" />
```

Full working example:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.type.TypeReference;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.message.ObjectMessage;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        HashMap<Object, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("foo", "bar");
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(map);

        Map<String, Object> newMap = new ObjectMapper().readValue(jsonObject.toString(), new TypeReference<Map<String, Object>>() {});

        Logger log4jLogger = LogManager.getLogger("mainLogger");
        log4jLogger.info(new ObjectMessage(newMap));
    }
}
```

This will produce:

```
{"thread":"main","level":"INFO","loggerName":"mainLogger","message":{"foo":"bar"},"endOfBatch":false,"loggerFqcn":"org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger","instant":{"epochSecond":1548434758,"nanoOfSecond":572000000},"threadId":1,"threadPriority":5}
```

Comment: not happening for me the it is logged as
{"timeMillis":1615981656315,"thread":"main","level":"INFO","loggerName":"com.ServiceApplication","message":"{foo=bar}"}

Comment: Me to when using log4j2 version 2.13.3 :(